# Coef and Polynomial equation

Tags: machine-learning, regression-coefficients, polynomial

I have a problem about the coef of polynomial, from machine learning.

```
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
train_y_ = clf.fit(train_x_poly, train_y)
# The coefficients
print ('Coefficients: ', clf.coef_)
print ('Intercept: ',clf.intercept_)
```

Coefficients:  [[ 0.         50.98399588 -1.59089505]]
Intercept:  [106.67723923]

```
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
XX = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
yy = clf.intercept_[0]+ clf.coef_[0][1]*XX+ clf.coef_[0][2]*np.power(XX, 2)
plt.plot(XX, yy, '-r' )
plt.xlabel("Engine size")
plt.ylabel("Emission")
```

My question is about this equation:

```
yy = clf.intercept_[0]+ clf.coef_[0][1]*XX+ clf.coef_[0][2]*np.power(XX, 2)
```

why they do not use the first coef [0][0], is because is '0'?

Comment: Without more context in which this code appears, we can only speculate. Who are 'they'? Can you link to where you found this, or construct a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: This is a code from IBM machine leaning class for polynomial regression.

Comment: If you need, this is the code before above codes I cited:         from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model
train_x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE']])
train_y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])

test_x = np.asanyarray(test[['ENGINESIZE']])
test_y = np.asanyarray(test[['CO2EMISSIONS']])

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
train_x_poly = poly.fit_transform(train_x)
train_x_poly

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, they don't use it because the coefficient is $0$. It is $0$ because the first coefficient of a polynomial feature generator in `sklearn` library is constant. Here is their [explanation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html):

> For example, if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a,
> b], the degree-2 polynomial features are $[1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2]$.

When the first feature is constant and you also fit the `intercept` in `LinearRegression` (LR), one of them becomes redundant. And, the constant feature is redundant because the `fit` procedure first standardizes the features, make them zero mean and unit variance (if possible). The constant feature, which is full $1$'s becomes a full $0$'s vector and whatever coefficient you multiply will have no effect. This is why it makes sense to have that coefficient $0$.

Comment: Thanks. So if the first coef is not '0', we should use it, shall we?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I have another question, if the first coef is not 0, how we fit the first coef to the equation, like yy = clf.intercept_[0]+ clf.coef_[0][0]*XX+ clf.coef_[0][1]*np.power(XX, 2)+ clf.coef_[0][2]*np.power(XX, 3)?  But the degree of polynomial was set to 2? Or shall we use the first coef to replace the intercept? Thanks again.

Comment: As per the explanation of `PolynomialFeatures`, you should have a matrix/vector of $1$'s for the first feature. That said, it's actually `np.power(XX, 0)` that corresponds to the first coef. Note that the power terms are by $1$.